# React.js: Invalid JSON when passing to axios POST request

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the value of a listbox to axios POST request

See code below:

```
const [selectedModules, setSelectedModules] = useState([]);

const onChange = selectedValues => {
    console.log("selectedValues " + selectedValues)
    setSelectedModules(selectedValues)
    retrieveActionsList(selectedValues)
  };

return (
<DualListBox
                options={ newOptionsListbox }
                selected={ selectedModules }
                onChange={ onChange }
                showHeaderLabels={ true }
            />
)
```

Axios POST request:

```
retrieveActionsList(selectedValues) {
    console.log("retrieveActionsList selectedValues1 >>> " + selectedValues)
    console.log("retrieveActionsList selectedValues2 >>> " + JSON.stringify(selectedValues))
    console.log("retrieveActionsList selectedValues4 >>> " + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedValues)))
        return axios.post(`${API_URL_RETRIEVE_ACTIONS}`,
        [
            {
                moduleId: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedValues))
            }
        ]
        )
    }
```

For some reason, I always get http status response 400

But when I hardcode moduleId to string(e.g. "92BC0710-6B61-4AFE-8402-955077613B79"), it works just fine

I'm pretty sure I'm also passing a String

TIA

Comment: Is selectedValues which you are passing in retrieveActionsList is json object?

Comment: If you are passing string then why are you doing JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedValues))

Comment: The selectedValues is the object passed to onChange={ onChange }. I'm not sure why I'm doing JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, but I just tried it all and whatever works. But none of it works

Comment: pass object as axios 2nd arg, not an array ... just `{ moduleId: selectedValues }` ... if API accepts array for this property ... comparing single hardcoded string to an array is inacurate

Comment: Yes, the API accepts array. How do I pass object as axios 2nd arg?

Comment: This does not work either { moduleId: selectedValues }

Comment: Somehow, I don't think the object selectedValues is passed as String. Wherein I want it to be a String